# continually refreshing ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made a simple chat script using jquery and AJAX but the huge hole in it is that i can only chat with myself properly :P

heres the javascript for my main file

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("#status").load('ajaxLoad.php');
$("#userArea").submit(function(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
var name = '<?php echo $name; ?>';


var url = "ajaxPost.php";
var msg = document.getElementById("messages").value;


 var vars = "messages="+msg+"&id="+id+"&name="+name;
hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        $("#status").append(return_data);
    }
}
hr.send(vars);
return false;});
 });
```

and heres my 2nd file "ajaxLoad.php"

```
<?php
include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT messages,id FROM chat");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {

echo $row["messages"];


    }
    ?>
```

Now what i need is to continually refresh "ajaxLoad.php" so that users can chat in realtime without refreshing the page...any way around this?

Comment: I encountered this while making a clock.  Lemme dig up that code for you.

Comment: http://thedogsbolloxs.com/clock.html check out the js there for some ideas on how to do an interval ajax call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// reload every second
setInterval(function() {
  $("#status").load('ajaxLoad.php');
}, 1000);
```

Be careful of making too requests to the server. It's going to be rather intensive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript `setInterval` to call your php script every x seconds.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get bleeding edge, you should look into [WebSockets](http://websocket.org/).